# What is the most efficient way to include many javascript functions (with PHP in them) in a PHP page?

Tags: php, javascript

In one of my sites, I need to use PHP 'foreach' to keep including some Javascript code. In this code contains PHP $variables that change within the foreach loop.

```
foreach ($a as $b) {
   include("javascript.php");  
}
```

javascript.php  contains codes like this:

```
<script>
   $(".<?php echo $somevariable?>").something;
</script>
```

My question is: What is the most efficient (if any) way to load javascript that contains PHP variables?

I keep reading that it's better to call large javascript codes in a .js script rather than writing it on the page, But apparently .js files can not have PHP.

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: .js, or any file, can have php in it, you just have to tell your server to parse the files as php

Comment: Thanks, what do I search for to get this done? is it a simple line of code I can put in the .js file or .php file?

Comment: If your external JS file is dynamically generated and changes with each request, there will be *more* overhead, not less. The chief performance benefit to moving your JS to an included file is that it can be cached across multiple requests. The important thing is to make your code secure and maintainable. Until you experience performance issues, you shouldn't be worrying about the most "efficient" way of doing *anything*, let alone including JS in your page.

Comment: @DankPiff No, it's a server configuration setting. You either need to write your JavaScript inside .php files, or configure your server to run files with .js extension through PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the approach I would use:

Create your HTML file with a Javascript variable containing $somevariable:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="my_global.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Foo
<script>
    var somevariable = "<?php echo $somevariable ?>";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then have the Javascript file access this value once the page is ready (I'm using jQuery .ready() in this example):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert(somevariable);
});
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/2zeQM/

This allows the Javascript file to be cached (it's static and not dynamic). And the dynamic data is loaded on the page being requested by the user.

You do need to be careful that the variable name you use does not get reused by any other Javascript code. To prevent problems, I would prefix the variable name. For example, instead of calling it "somevariable", I might call it "xy_somevariable"

Answer (score 1):

you can add:

```
header("Content-type: text/javascript");
```

to the top of your .php file and it will render as a .js file.

Comment: This isn't necessary; Including the file via a `<script src="file.php"></script>` is all that is necessary.